# Clear ptr_array

Tags: c++, boost

I want to clear ptr_array

```
boost::ptr_array<A, 10> a;
...
a.clear();  // missing
```

How do I clean ptr container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to behave like an array and you can not clear an array in `C++`. Only thing you can do is to set the individual elements to NULL.

Comment: What do you suggest for that: `a = boost::ptr_array<A, 10>()`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [class synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_array.html), calling `a.release();` will do the trick, as the docs state that a postcondition of calling `release` is that "all pointers are null."

Indeed, a glance at the implementation verifies this, although it's less efficient than strictly possible since it involves an unused/wasted (for your purposes) heap allocation:

```
std::auto_ptr<this_type> release()
{
    std::auto_ptr<this_type> ptr( new this_type );
    this->swap( *ptr );
    return ptr;
}
```